# Как правильно писать аббревиатуры в названии классов в Java

Tags: java, классы

Как правильно написать название класса FBXHeaderExtension или fbxHeaderExeption но это противоречит общепринятому правилу что классы пишется с заглавной буквы.

Comment: Тогда зачем писать с маленькой, если знаете, что противоречит?

Comment: FBX это сокращение из 3 слов.

Answer (score 2):

По java convensions четких рекомендаций на этот счет нет, конвенция рекомендует [по возможности избегать аббревиатур](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

По конвенции названия классов пишутся в UpperCamalCase стиле, насчет  аббревиатур в именах классов устоявшаяся практика - они пишутся маленькими буквами: `FbxHeaderExtension`.

Имена экземпляров такого класса по конвеции пишутся в lowerCamalCase стиле: `fbxHeaderExtension`.
В частности, если бы аббревиатура записывалась большими буквами, то мы получили бы довольно уродливое `fBXHeaderExtension`.

Однако в API Java есть имена классов обоих типов и их комбинаций: `HttpURLConnection`, `HTTPAddress`, `UrlPathHelper` поэтому преобладать болжен здравый смысл, видимо.

Обсуждение [на EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2236807/7566397)

Comment: а если FBX это сокращение от Filmbox все равно писать FbxHeaderExtension

Comment: идеально правильно в вашем случае писать  `FilmboxHeaderExtension`

Answer (score 1):

Из [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming):

> **5.2.2 Class names**
>
> Class names are written in UpperCamelCase.
>
> Class names are typically nouns or noun phrases. For example,
>   *Character* or *ImmutableList*. Interface names may also be nouns or noun
>   phrases (for example, *List*), but may sometimes be adjectives or
>   adjective phrases instead (for example, *Readable*).